# Using a return value from a function immediately instead of saving it as a variable as a middle step

Tags: python

I find that it's too often the case that there's no need to store some function's return value as a variable. I'd like to skip that bit and use it directly.

Current method:

```
def some_function():
    return 1, 2

values_1 = []
values_2 = []

for _ in range(5):
    value_1, value_2 = some_function()
    
    values_1.extend(value_1)
    values_2.extend(value_2)
```

What I'd like to do instead:

```
def some_function():
    return 1, 2

values_1 = []
values_2 = []

for _ in range(5):
    values_1.extend(_returned_1_), values_2.extend(_returned_2_) = some_function()
```

Is there a “Pythonic” way to do so?

Comment: There are probably ways to bend over backwards to send an iterable to two different functions… but what you're doing is already the simplest and most comprehensible way to do it.

Comment: Not really... Fitting everything on one line isn't always a good idea

Comment: `[l.extend(a) for l, a in zip((values_1, values_2), some_function())]`… But… yeah… no…

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should refactor it so that the function makes side effect on the lists themselves?

```py
def some_function(l1: list, l2: list) -> None:
    l1.extend(1)
    l2.extend(2)

values_1 = []
values_2 = []

for _ in range(5):
    some_function(values_1, values_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can avoid the repeated code by using an indirection on you data:

```
listOfLists = [values_1,values_2] # indirect access to lists
for _ in range(5):
    for values,value in zip(listOfLists,some_function()):
        values.extend(value)
```